# What does the function do while it returns 0?

Tags: windows, c++

I wrote a simple C++ code and compiled it in VS 2013. I am trying to understand what happen after return 0.

```
int main(){
...
    return 0;
...
}
```

The assembly code of return 0, translates to the xor eax, eax

```
011F1B19  xor         eax,eax  
}
011F1B1B  pop         ebp  
011F1B1C  ret
```

After ret, it jumps to 011F121A

```
011F1203  push        dword ptr ds:[11F3034h]  
011F1209  push        dword ptr ds:[11F3030h]  
011F120F  push        dword ptr ds:[11F302Ch]  
011F1215  call        main (011F1B00h)  
011F121A  add         esp,0Ch  
011F121D  mov         dword ptr ds:[011F3024h],eax  
011F1222  cmp         dword ptr ds:[11F3028h],0
011F1229  jne         __tmainCRTStartup+144h (011F1261h)
#ifndef _CRT_APP
                exit(mainret);
011F122B  push        eax  
011F122C  call        dword ptr ds:[11F2078h]
```

I have two questions:

1. Why does the return translates to xor eax, eax?
2. Why does the function dereference ptr in ds segments at 011F121D and 011F1222 and 011F122C?

Comment: Your questions were answered below. But as an aside, if you want to remove the C runtime code from your executable, you can [set the entry point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e.aspx) to your `main` function (assuming you're not using any functions from the C runtime in your code).

Answer (score 6):

```
xor eax, eax
```

Is the fastest way to zero a register. You will see this *everywhere* on x86. All x86 ABIs specify that an integer return value is placed in the `eax` register.

`ds` is the default segment for most memory accesses. Your disassembler is just being explicit.

I'm not familiar with the specifics on Windows, but basically the C runtime stub compiled into your program will take the return value from main, and pass it to a system call to exit the process. (Returning from `main` is equivalent to calling `exit`.)

Comment: Incidentally, this is the proper way to exit under UNIX style environments as well.  A syscall with the return code set either on the stack or in a register.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer syscall arguments on x86 are always in registers.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  I had the differences between cdecl, pascal and fastcall and functions in my head, but all user mode calls for system calls on x86 will be in registers.

Answer (score 2):

The xor reason is obvious. the return value.
when using c++ in x86/64 land the return value of functions stores in EAX register before return.
because you wrote "return 0" the value of eax must be 0:

`opcode: b8 00 00 00 00`
`asm:mov eax, 0*`

the optimizer make better choice:

`opcode: 31 c0`
`asm: xor eax, eax`

so the result is equal eax = 0 with optimization.

about the "*011F3024h*", since OS must take care of return value of each program, it must save your return address for later use. this is it ( for simple answer )
for more detailed answer read RE of __tmainCRTStartup